# The Use of SQL Check Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am currently using SQL Server 2012 and am needing some help with adding a SQL Check Constraint to a column, I have an exsisting table and on a column I want the user to be able to only enter one of three things, these would be as follows :-

IEU

None IEU

The third thing is if they type in none of the 2 options above the only other things they could type in is

_ _ _ / _ _ _ _

the underscores can be either a letter or a number but must include the forward slash after the first 3 characters so the entry would have to be in this format.

In the ideal world this would be done at the application layer but I have no ability to edit this as its a specific piece of licenced software.

The only way I can think about doing this is with using the SQL Check Constraint option but I am not sure how to do this to cover all 3 scenarios.

Can anyone help. Thanks P

Comment: Something like `CHECK <yourcolumn> IN ('IEU', 'None IEU') or <yourcolumn> like '<your regexp>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
ALTER TABLE <YourTable>
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_YOURTABLE_COL  
    CHECK(Col IN('IEU' , 'None IEU') OR Col LIKE '___/____')
```

*`Col` is the column with the `CHECK` constraint*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CHECK ((ColumnName = 'IEU') OR (ColumnName = 'None IEU') OR
(ColumnName LIKE '[a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]/[a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]'))
);
```

This way will make sure that only letters or numbers can be used. The '_' allows any non-reserved character.